# Breaks in a LogPlot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to plot the residuals of a pde solution, using `LogPlot`.

```
Clear[pde1]
pde1 = D[u[t, x], t] - (D[u[t, x], x]) == 
   D[D[u[t, x], x], x] + 
    D[u[t, x], x]^2*D[D[u[t, x], x], x] - (u[t, x] - u0);
ics = {u[0, x] == 0};
bcs = {{u[t, 0] == 1 + l1*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0]}, {u[t, lb] == 
     u0}};

mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf, "ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

l1 = 0.5; u0 = 0; tend = 15; lb = 5;

pts = 120;

{sol} = NDSolve[{pde1, ics, bcs}, {u}, {x, 0, lb}, {t, 0, tend}, 
   Method -> Union[mol[pts, 4], mol[True, 100]]];

pp1 = LogPlot[
  Subtract @@ (D[u[t, x], t] - (D[u[t, x], x]) == 
        D[D[u[t, x], x], x] + 
         D[u[t, x], x]^2*D[D[u[t, x], x], x] - (u[t, x] - u0)) /. 
     sol /. t -> 15 // Evaluate, {x, 0, lb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

In the above plot there are breaks, How can I avoid these?

Comment: They indicate areas of pure negative values.  Use Plot rather than LogPlot and you can see that.

Answer (score 1):

The plotargument is negative, `Log[]` cannot evaluate a real value:

If you increase the WorkingPrecision in  `NDSolve`

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{pde1, ics, bcs}, {u}, {x, 0, lb},{t, 0, tend},Method -> Union[mol[pts, 4], mol[True, 100]]
,WorkingPrecision -> 10];
```

[image]

one gap disappears!

**remark**

check the messages of NDSolve `NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve.` ...